# Forward a subdomain to another domain's subdomain

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

I have Wordpress multisite with subdomain setting. Now I want to change the domain name.

www.sample.com to www.sample.net

How can I redirect all subdomains in .com to .net with a simple .htaccess redirect regex?

```
aaa.sample.com to aaa.sample.net
bbb.sample.com to bbb.sample.net
ccc.sample.com to ccc.sample.net
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.net%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Make sure this rule is very first rule.

Answer (score 0):

RedirectMatch ^(.+).sample.com(/.*)? $1.sample.net$2 [R=301,L]

I did not test regex syntax, I coded this straight from my head. This will redirect rather than rewrite. The URI relative to domain will not be changed.